# How to select only field of embeded document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection that contains a document like the following:
[image]

I just want to get id of quiz

[image]

But my result expected is

```
{"id":1}
```

How to do that?

Comment: just try only `{ 'quizId': '$quiz.id', '_id': 0 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works with MongoDB version 4.4 or higher:

Input document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "quiz" : { "id" : 1, "time_limit" : 10 } }
```

The query uses the new functionality in projection:

```
db.names.find( { }, { "id" : "$quiz.id", "_id": 0 } )

{ "id" : 1 }  // desired output
```

For more information see [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an aggregation [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage as the query language does not allow restructuring of data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: "$quiz.id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/elzZAvrJ--F)